Clustering Artemis ActiveMQ in k8s with primary replicas only
I'm trying to cluster my Artemis ActiveMQ instance in k8s environment. I deployed the service as StatefulSet with 3 replicas. At the very begging my cluster settings looks fine as I'm able to see the result in webconsole

While I add queue with this command everything seems to be alright
./artemis perf producer --url tcp://activemq:61616 --user admin --password admin --message-size 1024 --message-count 1000 --rate 100 queue://test-queue1


The result of this command look like this
--- warmup false 
--- sent:            99 msg/sec 
--- blocked:          0 msg/sec 
--- completed:       99 msg/sec

--- warmup false 
--- sent:            99 msg/sec 
--- blocked:          0 msg/sec 
--- completed:       99 msg/sec

--- SUMMARY
--- result:              success
--- total sent:             1000
--- total blocked:             2
--- total completed:        1000 
--- aggregated delay send time: mean:    110.92 us - 50.00%:     84.00 us - 90.00%:    109.00 us - 99.00%:    169.00 us - 99.90%:   5759.00 us - 99.99%:  15167.00 us - max:     15167.00 us 
--- aggregated send time:       mean:    175.91 us - 50.00%:    120.00 us - 90.00%:    267.00 us - 99.00%:    417.00 us - 99.90%:    827.00 us - 99.99%:  24063.00 us - max:     24063.00 us

However when I'm about to consume queue with this command it doesn't work as expected with every single run
./artemis perf consumer --url tcp://activemq:61616 --user admin --password admin --message-count 1000 queue://test-queue1

/var/lib/artemis-instance/bin $ ./artemis perf consumer --url tcp://activemq:61616 --user admin --password admin --message-count 1000 queue://test-que
ue1
Connection brokerURL = tcp://activemq:61616

--- warmup false 
--- received:         0 msg/sec

--- warmup false 
--- received:         0 msg/sec
^C^C^C^C
--- SUMMARY
--- result:              success
--- total received:            0 
--- aggregated transfer time:   mean:      0.00 us - 50.00%:      0.00 us - 90.00%:      0.00 us - 99.00%:      0.00 us - 99.90%:      0.00 us - 99.99%:      0.00 us - max:         0.00 us
/var/lib/artemis-instance/bin $ ./artemis perf consumer --url tcp://activemq:61616 --user admin --password admin --message-count 1000 queue://test-que
ue1
Connection brokerURL = tcp://activemq:61616

--- SUMMARY
--- result:              success
--- total received:         1000 
--- aggregated transfer time:   mean: 43612897.28 us - 50.00%: 43778047.00 us - 90.00%: 47710207.00 us - 99.00%: 48496639.00 us - 99.90%: 48758783.00 us - 99.99%: 48758783.00 us - max:    48758783.00 us

I think it's caused by k8s service object named activemq as it's working for 3 released pod as a loadbalancer
Anyway I thought that replication in ha policy allows me to have the very same data in all available replicas
My current cluster settings in broker.xml configuration looks like this. It needs to be the same for every single replica
My full broker.xml deployed on each node of artemis cluster
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
                xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <name>0.0.0.0</name>

        <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
                <connector-ref>loadbalancer</connector-ref>
                <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
                <retry-interval-multiplier>1.5</retry-interval-multiplier>
                <max-retry-interval>60000</max-retry-interval>
                <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
                <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                <static-connectors>
                    <connector-ref>loadbalancer</connector-ref>
                    <connector-ref>activemq0</connector-ref>
                    <connector-ref>activemq1</connector-ref>
                    <connector-ref>activemq2</connector-ref>
                </static-connectors>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

        <connectors>
            <connector name="loadbalancer">tcp://activemq-headless.mq.svc.cluster.local:61616</connector>
            <connector name="activemq0">tcp://activemq-0.activemq-headless.mq.svc.cluster.local:61616</connector>
            <connector name="activemq1">tcp://activemq-1.activemq-headless.mq.svc.cluster.local:61616</connector>
            <connector name="activemq2">tcp://activemq-2.activemq-headless.mq.svc.cluster.local:61616</connector>
        </connectors>

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

        <max-redelivery-records>1</max-redelivery-records>

        <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

        <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

        <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

        <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

        <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

        <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

        <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

        <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

        <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

        <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

        <journal-buffer-timeout>876000</journal-buffer-timeout>

        <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>

        <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

        <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

        <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

        <page-sync-timeout>1252000</page-sync-timeout>

        <global-max-messages>-1</global-max-messages>

        <acceptors>

            <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

        </acceptors>

        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
                <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>

        <address-settings>
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="#">
                <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
                <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
                <page-size-bytes>10M</page-size-bytes>
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>
                <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>
                <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>
                <page-limit-bytes>-1</page-limit-bytes>
                <page-limit-messages>-1</page-limit-messages>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>

        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ"/>
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="ExpiryQueue"/>
                </anycast>
            </address>

        </addresses>

    </core>
</configuration>

From my perspective the perfect solution is proper loadbalancing or data replication between each node
There're logs indicating that cluster is on
Pod 1:
2024-08-23 12:59:24,603 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@2c1a4f1e [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@6f969c3e targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@2c1a4f1e [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@6f969c3e targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1825071442[nodeUUID=84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local, address=test, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
2024-08-23 12:59:24,603 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@5415be89 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@7e9dc5cf targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@5415be89 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@7e9dc5cf targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1825071442[nodeUUID=84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local, address=test, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected

Pod 2
24-08-23 12:59:24,259 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@2c1a4f1e [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@6f969c3e targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@2c1a4f1e [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@6f969c3e targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1825071442[nodeUUID=8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local, address=test, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
2024-08-23 12:59:24,536 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@5415be89 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@7e9dc5cf targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@5415be89 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@7e9dc5cf targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1825071442[nodeUUID=8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local, address=test, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected

Pod 3
2024-08-23 12:59:24,258 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@5b288554 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@f09d304 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@5b288554 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.8476e6b2-614f-11ef-90e0-0a580a80037b, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@f09d304 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1825071442[nodeUUID=84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local, address=test, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
2024-08-23 12:59:24,467 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2024-08-23 12:59:24,534 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@63197767 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@6b13f953 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@63197767 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-cluster.84a2d8e4-614f-11ef-b402-0a580a83005d, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0], temp=false]@6b13f953 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1825071442[nodeUUID=84b48bb1-614f-11ef-97ee-0a580a820350, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local, address=test, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=0.0.0.0])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=loadbalancer, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61616&host=activemq-headless-mq-svc-cluster-local], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected

Console output after artemis perf producer

Console output after artemis perf consumer. I need to run this command several times in order to reach the node that contains this queue. Unexpectedly, I can see that consumer count remains 0 although queue has been consumed
 ./artemis perf consumer --url tcp://activemq:61616 --user admin --password admin --message-count 100 queue://test-queu
e1
Connection brokerURL = tcp://activemq:61616

--- SUMMARY
--- result:              success
--- total received:         1000 
--- aggregated transfer time:   mean: 84713930.75 us - 50.00%: 84934655.00 us - 90.00%: 89128959.00 us - 99.00%: 89653247.00 us - 99.90%: 89653247.00 us - 99.99%: 90177535.00 us - max:    90177535.00 us



As you advised I've removed ha-policy and added message redistribution with message-load-balancing set ON_DEMAND. Unfortunately I'm still struggling with the same issue

Yeah, please see updated logs

After you execute artemis perf producer can you confirm that one of the brokers has an address named test-queue1 and an anycast queue with the same name and that queue has a message count of 1000? Likewise, after you execute artemis perf consumer can you confirm that one of the other brokers has an address named test-queue1 and an anycast queue with the same name and that queue has a consumer count of 1?

There you go, please see

I'm a bit confused. In your latest update the consumer actually received all the messages. Isn't that the behavior you were saying doesn't work? Or did the consumer get created on the node where the messages were sent? Also, instead of using the artemis perf producer and artemis perf consumer commands can you use the simpler artemis producer and artemis consumer commands respectively?

It only works occasionally. If I run the command 10 times, it’s most likely to work at all. The load balancing system is not working as expected because my request can be handled by one of 3 nodes but 2 of them do not contain the necessary message so the request will always fail on those nodes. What I really need is a proper load balancing system. For example all nodes should be queried to see if they have the required queue and if not check another node or something similar. The main issue is that consumption work but not consistently theres only about a 33% success rate with 3 nodes deployed
